# C# - How to list out variable names and values posted to ASPX page

Tags: c#, html, webforms

I am dynamicaly generating a HTML form that is being submitted to a .aspx webpage. How do I determine in the resulting page what variable names were submitted and what the values were? Using:
    Request["VarName"].toChar();
Works, but assumes that I know all of the variable names. How can I get the names and values?

Ideally, the solution would work for both POST and GET submissions...

Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

**For post request:**

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys ) 
{
   Response.Write ( Request.Form[key] );
}
```

**For a get request:**

```
foreach(string key in Request.QueryString.Keys ) 
{
   Response.Write ( Request.QueryString[key] );
}
```

Comment: That worked after I changed Request.Form.keys to Request.Form.Keys, and similar for Request.QueryString.Keys. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I've come to rely on that intellisense to fix my case issues to much. =)

Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Each of `Request.Cookies`, `Request.Form`, `Request.QueryString` and Request.`ServerVariables` is a `NameValueCollection` or similar. You can ask each of those for its keys, and proceed from there.

```
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    string value = Request.QueryString[key];
    // etc
}
```

Quite which collections you need will depend on the purpose of this - if it's just for diagnostics, I'd be tempted to dump them all out.

Comment: Did you mean "Request.QueryString[key]", perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

JohnFx's method works well.  You can also include query string, server variable, and cookie data into the mix by using the Request.Params collection, as in:

```
foreach(string key in Request.Params.Keys)
{
  Response.Write(String.Format("{0}: {1}<br />", key, Request.Params[key]));
}
```

You need to be careful when using the `Request.Params` collection.  If a QUERYSTRING variable and FORM variable both share key "Name" and have values "Val1" and "Val2", then the value of `Request.Params["Name"]` will be "Val1, Val2."

Answer (score 1):

Don't read from the `Request` collection, that is a composite collection that contains form and querystring values, but also cookies and server variables. Read from the specific collections where you want the data from, i.e. the `Request.Form` (for POST) and `Request.QueryString` (for GET).

This is how you can get all the keys and values into a string:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("Form values:");
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys) {
   builder.Append("  ").Append(key).Append(" = ").AppendLine(Request.Form[key]);
}
builder.AppendLine("QueryString values:");
foreach (string keu in Request.QueryString.Keys) {
   builder.Append("  ").Append(key).Append(" = ").AppendLine(Request.QueryString[key]);
}
string values = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: But Request.Form contains POST headings like X-Requested-With and __RequestVerificationToken

Comment: contains HTTP* headings, I meant.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs: No, the `Request.Form` collection only contains form data sent in the request body, not HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948.aspx) as a collection.  Note that multi-valued parameters (a multi-select) are turned into a collection themselves.  There's an example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration of the .ASPX add Trace='True'

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Trace="True" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, if you want to combine collection of QueryString, Form, ServerVariables, and Cookies items, then the best way is to use **[HttpRequest.Params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration of the .ASPX add Trace='True'

```
<%@ Page Language="CS" Trace="True" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

You will be able to see the Forms data, Session, Application data etc.